# openssl equivalent to des command line

Tags: openssl

I have a simple des command line:

```
des -D -k "whatever" file.enc file.dec
```

des is version `des(1) built with libdes v 4.01 - 13-Jan-1997 - eay`

I would like to use openssl (version `OpenSSL 0.9.8a 11 Oct 2005`) instead but I cannot figure out the command line options. I think the closest (based on some random des man page) I have is

```
openssl enc -d -in file.enc -out file.dec -k "whatever" -iv 0 -des-cbc -nosalt
```

But no matter which command line options or algorithms I try, I keep getting the error:

```
5423:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:454:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: While openssl is a cryptographic tool, this doesn't seem as if it is quite on-topic here per our [FAQ]. It might be a better fit at one of our sister sites [SF] or [SU]. Moving the question should be taken care of automatically.

Comment: It seems to me that the question is less about the tool and more about understanding the permutations of the algorithm that are preventing the tool from working. I think it's either us or crypto. I'm going to give it a day and see if a crypto bear has an answer for us here.

Comment: When it comes to encryption, the openssl command line tool is very restricted in its input/output format, it expects a specific header. You'll probably have to either massage the ciphertext or use another tool. What format does this `des` utility use? Where is it from?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,Gilles. I think it was standard on Unix for a while, but may not be any more. [link](http://www.diablotin.com/librairie/networking/puis/ch06_06.htm) Can you suggest another tool that might be more appropriate than openssl?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
    [xxx@box ~]$ openssl enc -des-cbc  -k "whatever" -iv 0 -in file.enc -out file.dec
    [xxx@box ~]$ strings file.dec
    Salted__
    [xxx@box ~]$
```

Comment: Hi John, I'm looking to decrypt the file - I think this command line re-encrypts the file. Any ideas on how to decrypt?

Comment: then it should be: openssl enc -des-cbc -k "whatever" -iv 0 -d -in file.dec -out file.orig

Comment: When I try that, I get "Bad magic number".

Comment: What OS and OpenSSL version are you using? I've tried it with both Linux and AIX with two different openssl versions and both commands works fine.

Comment: @JohnSantos Did you perchance use the -nosalt option? Removing it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

By default the des program encodes the output as base64, so you need to decode that before passing to the decryption algorithm, OpenSSL provides the -a option to encode / decode base64.

The input to the DES decryption should start with the string “Salted__” if the input is base64 then this translates into “U2FsdGVkX18… “ at the beginning of the file.